# JSON parsing and getting images in android

Tags: android, json, listview, service, android-asynctask

I want to parse JSON object which contain string and images. My code is working but it's too slow to load image. I want to load images with another asynctask or service to decrease loading time. How can I achieve that? And which one is best approach using asynctask or service ? Here is my code

```
public class Traffic extends Fragment {
private ListView listView;
private HttpURLConnection connection = null;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
private InputStream inputStream = null;
private ArrayList<TrafficModelClass> trafficList;
private TrafficAdapter trafficAdapter;
private View view;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traffic,container,false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.trafficListView);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(),"" ,"Wait..." , true);
    new GetTrafficNews().execute();
    trafficList = new ArrayList<TrafficModelClass>();
    trafficAdapter = new TrafficAdapter(view.getContext() , R.id.trafficListView , trafficList);
    listView.setAdapter(trafficAdapter);
    return view;
}
public class GetTrafficNews extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.dtexeshop.com/Journalist/GetTrafficNews.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line="";

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = stringBuffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentJson = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentJsonArray = parentJson.getJSONArray("traffic");

            for (int i = 0; i < parentJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalJsonObject = parentJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                TrafficModelClass modelClass = new TrafficModelClass();
                modelClass.setUserName(finalJsonObject.getString("UserName"));
                modelClass.setDateTime(finalJsonObject.getString("DateTime"));
                modelClass.setHeadline(finalJsonObject.getString("Headline"));
                String string_url ="http://www.dtexeshop.com/Journalist/images/"+ finalJsonObject.getString("ImageName");
                URL urlImage = new URL(string_url);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlImage.openConnection().getInputStream());
                modelClass.setBitmapImage(image);
                modelClass.setDescription(finalJsonObject.getString("Description"));

                trafficList.add(modelClass);
                if(i==1){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        trafficAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use picasso library to fetch images this is perfect one for you . It won't delay in loading time it will load images according to network .

just use this line of code :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("url").into(imageview);
```

and add this dependency to your application.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call progressDialog.dismiss() in a non-UI thread, all operations on UI components should be done in the UI thread. In my humble opinion, the most common and modern approach is to perform such operations with RxJava framework. It allows you to write such alghorithms very easy in the functional way. But once you get familiar with it, you don't want to stop using it. My solution would look like this:

```
createDownloadObservable(url) // download json
    .map(json -> parseJson(json) // parse json text into a json object
    .map(jsonObject -> extractTrafficModel(jsonObject))) // extract list of TrafficModels from jsonObject
    .flatMap(trafficModelList -> Observable.from(trafficModelList)) // push every TrafficModel item in a pool
    .map(trafficModelItem -> downloadImage(trafficModelItem)) // download and set image for each TrafficModel item
    .toList() // aggreagate all items in a list
    .subscribe(new Subscriber() {
        public void onNext(List<TrafficModel> trafficModelList) {
            // here you are! You can do what you want to with this traffic model list
        }

        public void onError(Throable e) {
            // if some error appeared while passing the algorithm, you can process it here
        }
    })
```